# Mounting CIFS share using C++

Tags: windows, winapi, cifs

Is there a Windows C++ API to execute a command as a different user ? I am trying to mount a CIFS share from a service which is running as sys admin and I am currently logged in as a Kiosk user so when I try to mount the share using "net use .." I get access denied.

Comment: [A service should not directly access local or network resources through mapped drive letters, nor should it call the net use command to map drive letters at run time.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685143.aspx) Is there some reason that you can't just use the UNC path?

Comment: I can't use the UNC path directly.

Answer (score 0):

With [`CreateProcessWithLogin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw), you can execute a command with an arbitrary user provided you have valid credentials. Alternatively, can can use a combination of `LogonUser` and [`CreateProcessAsUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera) / [`CreateProcessWithToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithtokenw).

Rather than requiring credentials including a password stored as plaintext (not recommended from a security POV), you could also grant required permissions to the kiosk user so that the current user context is sufficient for accessing the data and/or mapping the network drive.

If that is not an option, your application could have a manually configured persistent network drive as a prerequisite. The credentials would then be managed by Windows.